# Angular re-direct via form submission with model data

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, redirect, data-binding

I'm having to implement 3D Secure payments in an Ionic/Angular application.  The application needs to make an API call to our server and on return from that it needs to re-direct the user to a 3rd Party website (pay360).

To perform the re-direct I need to create a form with three values on it and submit it programmatically.  If I hardcode the form with some values that I know work then **it all works ok and the re-direction to Pay360 is fine**:

```
<form #myForm action="https://dev.mite.pay360.com/acs" method="POST">
        <input name="MD" value="abc" />
        <input name="TermUrl" value="def" />
        <input name="PaReq" value="hij" />
</form>
```

However, if I try to insert the data into the form using data binding like this:

```
<form #myForm action="https://dev.mite.pay360.com/acs" method='POST'>
        <input [(ngModel)]="myModel.MD" name="MD"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="myModel.TermUrl" name="TermUrl"/>
        <input [(ngModel)]="myModel.PaReq" name="PaReq" />
</form>
```

it doesn't work even if in the component I plug in exactly the same values as I use when hardcoding the form as above e.g

```
this.myModel.TermUrl = "abc"
this.myModel.MD = "def";
this.myModel.PaReq = "hij";
this.myForm.nativeElement.submit()
```

The values all look good on screen as well just before the re-direction takes place so I know they are getting populated.

But when the Pay360 page appears it has a data validation error.

**So why does my hard-coded form re-direct successfully and my model-bound form fail?**

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked if I put a short delay in place before calling the submit method - so I guess the from was being submitted without the values even though they were being populated first.